# MySQL script not executing properly through python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, substring

Raw data:

Account
1234 � Rent

Running this in MySQL by manually executing a script, and then also executing the script using a Python shell:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Account,':',-1),' � ',-1) as Description,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Account,':',-1),' � ',1) as Acct_Number
FROM table1
```

MySQL Output (correct one)

```
Acct_Number    Description
1234             Rent
```

Python Output (incorrect one)

```
Acct_Number    Description
1234           1234 � Rent
```

Is there a way to get python to read this bizarre � character? Have successfully used Python to run script on similar Account data (also using substring index) that includes a - instead of this � character, and it works totally fine.

In case this character is not showing in this post, here is a link to which I am referring to: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD

Comment: It would be easier for people to help you if you post some code that you tried. What code did you use in python and which variable is showing that special character to you?

Answer (score 0):

See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the causes of "black diamond".

Also see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python for tips on using UTF-8 with Python and MySQL.

It may be important to find the hex that was actually stored -- to determine where the problem was on `INSERT` versus on display.

As you noted, hex `EFBFBD` represents the black diamond -- meaning that the problem was caused on the "storing" side of things.